# Nodejs - functions becomes undefined after exporting

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this on my **app.js** and I am exporting the `foo` object.

```
...some code

exports.foo = {
    bar: function(){
        return 'this is a test'
    }
}

...some code
```

Then on my other **test.js** file I am importing it like.

```
import foo from './path/to/app';
```

But when I tried to use `foo.bar()` I am getting this error `TypeError: _app2.default.bar is not a function`

Can someone explain what's happening here?

Comment: `import {foo} from './path/to/app';`

Comment: @TheReason that did it. :) Thanks!

Comment: @TheReason how did it happened though?

Comment: [This](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) link will be useful for you

Answer (score -1):

use this syntax

```
module.exports = {
        bar: function(){
            return 'this is a test'
        }
    }


var foo = require("./pathToFoo.js");

foo.bar();
```